# Why does Class#getComponentType return null instead of the generic type of ArrayList (Java)?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, dynamic-arrays, generic-collections

```
interface Borrowable {
  Date getCheckoutDate();
  Date getDudeDate();
  void setCheckoutDate(Date d);
  void setDudeDate(Date d);
}
```

next class has all the functions that an arraylist has. I have tested all of them and they work perfectly.

```
class LibraryCollection<E> {
  ArrayList<E> items = new ArrayList<>();

  public Iterator<E> iterator() {return items.iterator();}
  boolean add(E o) {return items.add(o);}
  boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {...}
...
.....
......
}
```

here is where I cannot figure up how to make " T[] getOverDueBooks(Date date)" to return a valid array. I am trying to do this cause it is a requirement in my java class.

```
class ChechOutCart<E extends Borrowable> extends LibraryCollection<E> {
  ArrayList<E> dueOnSpecificDate = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<E> dueOn = new ArrayList<>();

  <T> T[] getOverDueBooks(Date date) {
    T[] a = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(items.getClass().getComponentType(), items.size());
    Borrowable current;
    DVD d;
    Book b;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
      current = this.items.get(i);

      if (current instanceof Book) {
        b = (Book) current;
        if (date.after(b.getDudeDate())) {
          dueOn.add(this.items.get(i));
        }
      } else if (current instanceof DVD) {
        d = (DVD) current;
        if (date.after(d.getDudeDate())) {
          dueOn.add(this.items.get(i));
        }
      }
    } 
    return dueOn.toArray(a);
  }
}
```

in main I have made a cauple of DVD and Book objects and they are fully initialized I have omitted the initialization cause too long. I have put then in myCar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChechOutCart<Borrowable> myCar = new ChechOutCart<>();
    Borrowable[] array;

    DVD dvd1 = new DVD();
    DVD dvd2 = new DVD();
    Book book1 = new Book();
    Book book2 = new Book();

    myCar.add(book2);
    myCar.add(dvd1);
    myCar.add(book1);
    myCar.add(dvd2);

    array = myCar.getOverDueBooks(new Date(115, 03, 23));
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

and the errors that I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
at labb_part_b.ChechOutCart.getOverDueBooks(LabB_Part_B.java:40)
at labb_part_b.LabB_Part_B.main(LabB_Part_B.java:147)
Java Result: 1
```

I am new in java. any idea or examples that I can use to accomplish this task I will appreciate for ever... thanks

Comment: The question title could be improved. Suggestion: 'Why does Class#getComponentType not return the generic type of ArrayList?' Possibly related: [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

From the `Class#getComponentType` Javadoc:

> Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this
>   class does not represent an array class this method returns **null**.

`items` is an ArrayList, not an array. The generic type of an ArrayList is not accessible at runtime because of *Type Erasure*.

Not entirely sure why you want to return `T[]`. You might want to use `E` instead which already extends `Borrowable`. And if you really want to return an array, maybe cast after `toArray`?

Comment: thanks for your response and your time. I am trying to do this cause it is a requirement in my java class. I know your answer is correct but still I do not understand what is wrong, sorry about that but I'm pretty new at this. thanks again

Comment: I can only guess *what* you don't understand, but perhaps my edit clarified things anyway?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you do not understand? Maybe this helps: the component type of an array and the generic type of say an ArrayList are really two different beasts. You can access the component type at runtime with `Class#getComponentType` (only for arrays) but generic types - in general - are not available for introspection. There are some good questions about *Type Erasure* around here you might want to read for a better understanding of Java's type system. Thanks @meriton btw. Oops.

Comment: I got my idea how to deal with my problem from a definition that i found on internet that I guess it is the right definition of the function  'public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) { int size = size(); T[] r = a.length >= size ? a : (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance( etc etc etc ...' so I thought that I can use it in my code to get the array that I want to return in the same way that this function does. but I now know that I am wrong in that line and that helps me a lot because at the beginning I didn't know where I went wrong. thanks both